# a route doesn't match when there is a url parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router, all the routes render fine the components except the one using a URL parameter which returns a blank page when visiting `http://localhost:9000/edit/1`, and this error message in the console:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/edit/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

`bundle.js` is the compiled js file by webpack in my public directory.

When I changed the url from `/edit/:id` to `/:id` the url `http://localhost:9000/1` renders to the screen!

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import ExpenseDashboardPage from '../components/ExpenseDashboardPage';
import AddExpensePage from '../components/AddExpensePage';
import EditExpensePage from '../components/EditExpensePage';
import HelpPage from '../components/HelpPage';
import NotFoundPage from '../components/NotFoundPage';
import Header from '../components/Header';

const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
     <Header />
     <Switch>
       <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExpensePage} />
        <Route path="/" component={ExpenseDashboardPage} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/create" component={AddExpensePage} />
    
        <Route path="/help" component={HelpPage} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
     </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

here is the header file

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => (
 <header>
   <h1>Expensify</h1>
   <NavLink to="/" activeClassName="is-active" exact={true}>Dashboard</NavLink>
   <NavLink to="/create" activeClassName="is-active">Create Expense</NavLink>
   <NavLink to="/help" activeClassName="is-active">Help</NavLink>
 </header>
);
```

export default Header;

the components are identical, just simple stateless functions to render something to the screen.

```
import React from 'react';

const EditExpensePage = (props) => 
(
  <div>
    <h2>Edit Expense Page</h2>
    <p> expense with id: {props.match.params.id}</p>
  </div>
);
 export default EditExpensePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is more likely in the HTML returned from the server.

Look for something like

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

and try changing it to

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Loading page with URL like `http://localhost:9000/edit/1` the relative path `bundle.js` will get resolved as `http://localhost:9000/edit/bundle.js`, while absolute path `/bundle.js` says it should be resolved from the root of your public directory -> `http://localhost:9000/bundle.js`.

Comment: really thank you it fixed the problem ,so what's wrong i can't get it

Comment: See my edit with a bit of explanation and consider accepting the answer if it works for you. Unfortunately I don't have some great article to recommend for more info about this, just look around the web for some materials about resolving relative URIs.